# C++ Build Libcurl with HTTP/2.0 support (Existing version)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, libcurl, nghttp2

I have an existing LibCurl build, which currently isn't supporting the protocol HTTP/2.0, since I never linked it with the **nghttp2** software ([which is required](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html)).

Is it still possible to adjust the build and add this software to the build? If so, how can I do this. If not, could anyone give me the build details for a LibCurl build supporting:

- Static build
- HTTPS-support (OpenSSL, I have this library installed)
- HTTP/2.0 protocol support (nghttp2-software)

Thanks!

*P.s. I use Visual Studio 2017*

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. Do you want to take a binary and massage it into the state of HTTP/2.0 support, then no, it isn't doable. But why would you want that? Just build it again from the source.

Comment: @n.m., well thats quite a problem... I can't remember how I build it from source... I am looking on the internet as well, however I still can't find the right solution. I want to build a static LibCurl library, supporting HTTPS over 2.0 protocol. I have to build the code for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 with the build tools?